# Regelation, and melting ice with pressure

Tags: thermodynamics, fluid-statics, physical-chemistry, continuum-mechanics

It is an experimental fact (regelation) that if two weights are hung on the ends of a rigid bar, which passes over a block of ice, then the bar gradually passes through the block of ice. Moreover, the block remains intact even after the bar has passed completely through it. It is also a fact that less mass (for the two weights) is required if a semi-flexible bar is used (assume that the bar is otherwise of the same dimensions), rather than a rigid bar.

It is this latter fact which is escaping me, why is this? One can show using the Clapeyron equation that one needs to apply some large pressure (call it $P$) locally to the ice to achieve melting locally. In the case of the rigid bar, the laws of mechanics say that the force is distributed evenly throughout the bar and we can thereby determine the pressure applied by the bar to the ice. I do not know enough about continuum mechanics to understand what happens when the bar is flexible. Is the distribution of pressure then such that certain parts of the bar exert larger pressures for fixed masses, and this then causes melting locally (at pressure $P$) at a mass of the weights which is otherwise lower?

Comment: Just think of what happens at the very beginning.  if the bar is sufficiently flexible, its weight get concentrated on the outer edges of the cube.

Comment: So would you generally agree with my assessment? That the pressure on the outside is higher than it otherwise would be with a rigid bar. @Buzz

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A search for `regelation ice flexible beam` in Google Scholar yields as the very first result "[Paths swept out by initially slack flexible wires when cutting soft solids; when passing through a very viscous medium; and during regelation](https://royalsocietypublishing.org/doi/full/10.1098/rspa.2006.1747?casa_token=Vo_v8vGZgogAAAAA%3ACkH8K2f6eUtF24K7pQP93ZYfUOnBDDeghIkUa0cqOtVuJxcfumJDu7XfHU9GXECBHeo4-3Sx6tpM0Q)," which gives an analysis of the pressure, pressure-induced melting, and curve shape, with references to previous literature:

[image]

A simplifying assumption is made that the wire (unlike a beam) has negligible bending stiffness, but this doesn't really affect the key aspect: **When the wire/beam is curved, the load is applied to a smaller cross-section than the width of the block**. (A perfectly rigid bar always loads the entire width of the block.)

To prove this to yourself, try drawing lines connecting points where the wire/beam straightens; the lines are shortest at sharper corners, and so the stress (load per cross-sectional area) and thus the regelation speed are the highest there.

(A no-friction assumption is handy for the wire case because it allows the tension to be considered constant; see the literature on [four-point bending](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Four-point_flexural_test) for guidelines on analyzing the beam case.)

Comment: Fascinating, thank you. Much of this is beyond the scope of what I know, but I think that "When the wire/beam is curved, the load is applied to a smaller cross-section than the width of the block" captures what I need to understand (for now at least!).